# Sending Request to SOAP API in C# : Received an invalid header line: Cache-Control Value

Tags: c#, api, soap

I'm new to sending a request to a SOAP API and I keep encountering this error

```
'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Received an invalid header line: 'Cache-Control Value: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0'
```

My code is :

```
var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
{
    RequestUri = new Uri("https://somewhere/mySOAPAPI"),
    Method = HttpMethod.Post
};

request.Content = new StringContent(soaprequest, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");

request.Headers.Clear();

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));

request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");

request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/IExternalSolutionExecution/ExecuteXMLString");

request.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue();    

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

Console.WriteLine(response);var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
{
    RequestUri = new Uri("https://somewhere/mySOAPAPI"),
    Method = HttpMethod.Post
};

request.Content = new StringContent(soaprequest, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");

request.Headers.Clear();

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));

request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");

request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/IExternalSolutionExecution/ExecuteXMLString");

request.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue();
    
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

Console.WriteLine(response);
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Is it in the headers or in the content.

Answer (score 0):

I think the server is complaining about your cache settings:

```
request.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue();
```

Did you already try sending the request without that line?

Comment: yes I did. it's still encountering the error